# How to deal with DM favoritism?

Tags: dnd-4e, problem-players, problem-gm

I've been playing a 4e dungeons and dragons campaign for a while now, and it's the first campaign I've ever played in. The DM seems to keep pampering one player in particular. He usually only gives plot hooks to that player, never blames that player for anything, gives that player any and all magical items he wants, and let that player start out the game with a feat that allows him to take two standard actions per turn without spending an action point. The player claims that us other players are just bad at the game, even though his character sheet has multiple very clear errors. The thing is, this player is the only reason that we can win any battles since he's a higher level than any of us and the DM scales bosses to him. The DM has recently started giving plot hooks to other players, but the only time this has happened was when he gave my character a single hook one session ago. I'm sorry for ranting, I would just like to know how to deal with this.

Comment: Do you all use DDI to build your character sheets? What level is the party? Do you know what the purported feat name is?

Comment: The feat doesn't have a name, it was homebrewed. We all used DDI. We're all around mid-level 5, though the player is almost level 7.

Comment: Does the GM (wish to) have a special relationship with the player in question (eg., boy/girl-friend, spouse, sibling, best friends from way back, ...)? That might color the answers you'll get. (edit: not that those statuses are excuses, of course)

Comment: @minnmass Those statuses aren't *excuses* for favoritism but the only acceptable reasons *for* favoritism. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are lots of problems at this table. First of all, a DM should never blame a player for anything in game. DM is a referee, not a punisher. Giving away magical items whenever a player desires a certain item is just as problematic. Magical items should be treated with care because they tend to break the game if usage and access is abused. One level difference should not be a big issue when dealing with encounters but awarding the high level PC with magical items he wants, will throw the balance away. This is especially serious in D&D 4e.

Try to talk to your DM and tell him you are not having fun in this way. If he is deliberately favoring a certain player (maybe a girlfriend, a relative or close friend) it is very hard to convince him against it. If it does not work don't continue the game, because it clearly will not be fun or you. Try to find like minded people and group with them.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't discard the level differences so lightly. 4e is very much balanced around the party all being about the same level. With the favored player 2 levels higher than the rest of the party, plus the party facing enemies that are tuned to face that player specifically (who has a free action point every turn), a two level difference is probably a significant disadvantage. Even if the characters were more even except for a two level difference, it would start to be a significant problem if that gap continues to widen.